# Polars : Is there a json_normalize like feature in Polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I went through the entire documentation of Polars but couldn't find anything which could convert nested json into dataframe.

```
test = {
  "name": "Ravi",
  "Subjects": {
    "Maths": 92,
    "English": 94,
    "Hindi": 98
  }
}
```

json_normalize in pandas would convert this to a dataframe by naming the columns as name, Subjects.Maths, Subjects.English and Subjects.Hindi. So is this a possibility in Polars? I did try all the functions but it always throws an error as it doesn't undersand the nested structure.

Comment: There is no json_normalize in Polars like there is in Pandas. You may want to use another package to flatten the dict first, such as https://pypi.org/project/json-flatten/

Comment: AFAIK the arrow2 crate doesn't deal with nested structs very well

Answer (score 9):

For a simple JSON-like dictionary, you can use a comprehension list to convert the values into list of values.

Below an example:

```
grades = {
  "name": "Ravi",
  "Subjects": {
    "Maths": 92,
    "English": 94,
    "Hindi": 98
  }}

grades_with_list = {key:[value] for key, value in grades.items()}
pl.DataFrame(grades_with_list)

# Output
shape: (1, 2)
┌──────┬────────────┐
│ name ┆ Subjects   │
│ ---  ┆ ---        │
│ str  ┆ struct[3]  │
╞══════╪════════════╡
│ Ravi ┆ {92,94,98} │
└──────┴────────────┘

# You can also un-nest the Subjets column, to get a separate column for each subject.

pl.DataFrame(grades_with_list).unnest('Subjects')

# Output
shape: (1, 4)
┌──────┬───────┬─────────┬───────┐
│ name ┆ Maths ┆ English ┆ Hindi │
│ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---   │
│ str  ┆ i64   ┆ i64     ┆ i64   │
╞══════╪═══════╪═════════╪═══════╡
│ Ravi ┆ 92    ┆ 94      ┆ 98    │
└──────┴───────┴─────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: See more examples of `unnest` [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7078#issuecomment-1441905809) also see the new `json_extract` [here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7222) (instead of the comprehension)

Answer (score 3):

No there is not, AFAIK it is recommended to use the pandas function and then load the pandas data frame into polars.

Comment: I think the OP's main goal would be avoiding using Pandas. Maybe volumes are too large to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Polars does not have such functionality. But it's basically a utility thing, rather than a dataframe related concept. So as the other replies mentioned, it'd be better to use other solutions.

[flatdict](https://github.com/gmr/flatdict) is a nice fit for this issue

```
In [376]: test = {
     ...:   "name": "Ravi",
     ...:   "Subjects": {
     ...:     "Maths": 92,
     ...:     "English": 94,
     ...:     "Hindi": 98
     ...:   }
     ...: }

In [377]: pl.DataFrame(dict(flatdict.FlatDict(test, delimiter=".")))
Out[377]:
shape: (1, 4)
┌──────┬────────────────┬──────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ name ┆ Subjects.Maths ┆ Subjects.English ┆ Subjects.Hindi │
│ ---  ┆ ---            ┆ ---              ┆ ---            │
│ str  ┆ i64            ┆ i64              ┆ i64            │
╞══════╪════════════════╪══════════════════╪════════════════╡
│ Ravi ┆ 92             ┆ 94               ┆ 98             │
└──────┴────────────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────┘
```